# Windows has triggered a breakpoint in myprogram.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, types

Windows has triggered a breakpoint in `myprogram.exe`.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in `myprogram.exe` or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while `projtest.exe` has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information.

Working code:

```
void main()
{
    const unsigned char a_size = 15;
    int *a = new int[a_size];
    memset(a,0,a_size*sizeof(a));
    delete [] a;
}
```

Error code:

```
void main()
{
    const unsigned char a_size = 15;
    char *a = new char[a_size];
    memset(a,0,a_size*sizeof(a));
   >delete [] a;
}
```

`'>'` is breakpoint position.

So, char type in dynamic arrays causing errors.

Additional Info : Using Visual Studio C++ 2008

Comment: this is **NOT** a `C` program.

Comment: As pts implies in his answer, your first example only works because integers and pointers are the same size on your platform. Otherwise, undefined behavior would happen just like in the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A star is missing within sizeof:

```
memset(a,0,a_size*sizeof(*a));
```

That's because:

```
sizeof(a) == sizeof(int*)  -- usually 4 or 8
sizeof(*a) == sizeof(int)  -- usually 4
```

Comment: @user694733: a_sizeof is not standard C++. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Aww. Perfect! Thanks.
@user694733 'a_size' is variable.

Comment: I would rather use `sizeof( int )` because it is easier to understand the programmers intention

Comment: @lifeOfPI: I would rather use `sizeof(*a)` in case the base type of `a` changes in the future.